# getting swagger to run in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've inherited a class library that is using .NET Framework 4.7.2. In the library there are a  bunch of ApiControllers with a number of HttpPost and HttpGet Methods on them. Errors have started occurring on some of the methods and these methods are typically called from a wordpress site.

To try and make things a bit easier for me to debug, I'm trying to install swagger into the solution. I've installed Swashbuckle.core with a runtimne version of 4.0.30319 and this has created a basic SwaggerConfig.cs file in my App_Start folder.

In the properties for the solution the project url is http://localhost/WordpressService and it's running under local IIS.

I have a local version of wordpress running in Microsoft Edge, and in IIS I can see that the WordpressService is running on port 80.

So now in the WordpressService solution I try to attach the debugger to the browser, then in the browser I try to enter http://localhost/WordpressService/swagger and other variations of the address, but all the time I receive the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler
> "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module
> "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

I have this section in my web.config file:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer> >
```

within IIS in the Handler Mappings section I can see **ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0** and it is enabled.

it also suggests that asp.net may not be installed correctly but it must be as I'm using VS 2017 and would need to be there for that. Looking around the net, the default SwaggerConfig.cs should be enough to get me going.

The only thing I can think of is that I may have installed the wrong version of swagger, but I'm not sure in that case which version I should be installing for this .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured the issue out and thought I'd post my answer for anyone else that may come across this issue. From IIS installation, it appears that only Framework 3.5 had been installed and not Framework 4.8. Installing 4.8 in the IIS section seems to have resolved this and I can now see my end points via swagger.